# Determinant division problem

Tags: matrices, determinant

In linear algebra, if we have two matrix $n$ x $n$ matrix or same order $n$, their determinant multiplication can be given by: $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$.

Here is a variation of the problem I am in doubt, consider the formula of
$$
\ln\left(\frac{\det(A+B)}{\det (A)}\right).
$$

is it justified to to lead to following result: $\ln[\det(A^{-1})(A+B)]=\ln[\det(I+A^{-1}B)]$?

Please provide an answer and justified the derivation is valid/invalid.

Comment: This looks like a hw problem. What have you tried?

Comment: As written above...and, of course, $\;A\;$ must be regular.

Comment: It's not a homework problem,  I was reading some derivation related to Christoffel symbol, the author use this expression in a step of derivation, yet I am not sure is it justified to do so. I tried so specific case, yet I am not able to provide a general proof for it.

Comment: From the multiplicative property of the determinant applied to $A$ and $B=A^{-1}$ you get that $\det(A)\det(A^{-1})=\det(AA^{-1})=\det(I)=1$. Therefore, $\frac{1}{\det(A)}=\det(A^{-1})$. So, in the expression $\ln\left(\frac{\det(A+B)}{\det(A)}\right)$ you can replace the $\frac{1}{\det(A)}$ by $\det(A^{-1})$ to get $\ln(\det(A^{-1})\det(A+B))$. Next you use again the property to merge those two determinants as $\ln(\det(A^{-1}(A+B)))$. Finally distribute the matrix multiplication $\ln(\det(A^{-1}A+A^{-1}B))=\ln(\det(I+A^{-1}B))$.